# complex sql query using two tables and regexp

Tags: jquery, sql, regex, autocomplete

I need some help for a complex query. I'm using **autocomplete jquery-ui** for search some users and php+mysql to search.

Users can register with his `first_name`, `last_name` and `email` (requiered fields) on a wordpress/buddypress page.

so, is easy search with regexp on an example that i find on stackoverflow, but i want a make a complex query to search by first_name or last_name or email.

`first_name` and `email` are in **wp_users** table and `last_name` is in **wp_bp_xprofile_data** table. i don't want make a custom meta to join names and emails so,

To obtain the `first_name` and `email`, the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE display_name REGEXP '^$param' OR user_email REGEXP '^$param'
```

and to obtain de `last_name`, the query is:

```
SELECT value FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = 5 AND user_id = ".$id."
```

(value is last_name's result and $id=wp_users.ID)

**How can a mix this queries?**
if we see this like one table it would be like :`selec * from users where first_name=regexp or last_name=regexp or email=regexp` (basically), but by the complex structure of wordpress/buddypress i can't do this. please help!!!

eg...3 users, the name of the first user is oscar, the last name of the second user is osbourne, and the email of the third user is omnix.x@gmail.com, if the search starts with 'o', the query will find this 3 users.

PS: i forgot but i need to return the id, first name, last name and email.

Bonus: i'm using the regexp ^$params to find the string at the begin characters. what regexp is better to find this on the everywhere results?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from joining the two tables?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the right answer is:

```sql
SELECT u.ID, u.display_name, u.user_email, d.value
FROM wp_users u, wp_bp_xprofile_data d
WHERE
(
  u.ID IN (
        SELECT ID
        FROM wp_users
        WHERE display_name REGEXP '^$param'
  )
  OR u.ID IN (
        SELECT user_id as ID2
        FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data
        WHERE field_id = 5 AND value REGEXP '^$param'
  )
)
AND (u.ID=d.user_id AND field_id=5)
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users
WHERE display_name REGEXP '^$param'
   OR user_email REGEXP '^$param'
   OR concat('.',id,'.') IN 
      (SELECT user_id FROM wp_bp_profile
       WHERE field_id = 5 AND value REGEXP '^$param')
```

Comment: i forgot but i need to return the id, first name, last name and email. this solution don't work for last names